# Try catch arrays in windows form

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, user-interface, try-catch

I am making a windows form application that takes various game entries (title,genre,price) and then stores them in an array with a maximum of four entries.I also have a delete button to overide entries

I currently have 3 errors I am not sure if I ask about each error individually or all of them at the same time but I will try them all at the same time

1.when using the delete button to write over an array it maintains the original price value instead of changing to a string and being listed as sold

2.when I delete the second array using the delete button which is game 2 it instead overides the 1st but the 3rd and 4th arrays when being writed over work fine

3.when the user inputs something other than a decimal in the tb for price which is a decimal the whole program crashes how do I put in maybe a try catch statement to fix this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace gameForm
{
    public partial class gameEntryForm : Form
    {
        public gameEntryForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    struct Game
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Genre;
        public decimal Price;
    }

    static Game[] aNewGame = new Game[4]; //max size of the array is 4 

    static int newGameEntryIndex = 1;

    //bool full = true;

    private void gameEntryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aNewGame[0].Title = "golf tour"; //this is a game already stored in the database
        aNewGame[0].Genre = "sports";
        aNewGame[0].Price = 1.99m;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbGenre.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game genre.");
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbTitle.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game title");
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPrice.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter a Game price");
        }
        else
        {
            if (newGameEntryIndex >= 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the game store is full");

            }
            else
            {
                aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex] = new Game();

                aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Title = tbTitle.Text;

                aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Genre = tbGenre.Text;

                aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbPrice.Text);

                newGameEntryIndex++;

                MessageBox.Show("entry saved");

                //clears the text boxes 
                tbTitle.Clear();

                tbGenre.Clear();

                tbPrice.Clear();


            }
        }
    }
    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbShow.Text = "Game Details \n\nGame 1 \n" + aNewGame[0].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[0].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[0].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 2 \n" + aNewGame[1].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[1].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[1].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 3 \n" + aNewGame[2].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[2].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[2].Price + "\n\n" + "Game 4 \n" + aNewGame[3].Title + "\n" + aNewGame[3].Genre + "\n" + aNewGame[3].Price; ;
    }
    //clears the rich text box
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbShow.Clear();
    }
    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(cmbDelete.SelectedIndex == 1))
        {
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 0].Title = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 0].Genre = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 0].Price.ToString("Sold");
        }
        else if (!(cmbDelete.SelectedIndex == 2))
        {
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 1].Title = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 1].Genre = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 1].Price.ToString("sold");
        }
        else if (!(cmbDelete.SelectedIndex == 3))
        {
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 2].Title = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 2].Genre = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 2].Price.ToString("sold");
        }
        else if (!(cmbDelete.SelectedIndex == 4))
        {
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 3].Title = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 3].Genre = "Sold";
            aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex - 3].Price.ToString("sold");
        }
    }

 }

}
```

[image: this is an image of my form showing the second error]

Comment: How many entries are present in that ComboBox? Why do you subtract a constant from the SelectedIndex? The SelectedIndex should be already correct to set the "sold" text in the correct place inside the Game array

Comment: "maybe a try catch statement to fix this" - Nope. You're masking the real issue. Handle this in a way where a try/catch isn't necessary in the first place. You're certainly able to get some useful info from the exception, and hopefully it should be obvious enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try something like this for your `Show` button. I added the inline if statement because you cannot put a `string` into a `decimal` object. So we will modify the `Delete` button behavior.

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbShow.Text = "Game Details \n\n"
    for(int i = 0; i < aNewGame.Length; i++)
    {
        rtbShow.Text += Game " + i + 
            "\n" + aNewGame[i].Title + 
            "\n" + aNewGame[i].Genre + 
            "\n" + aNewGame[i].Price == Decimal.Zero ? "Sold" : aNewGame[i].Price;
    }
}
```

Now for the `Delete` button. Instead of `aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Price.ToString("Sold");` becasue this will produce a syntax error, you should do something like what Xtros suggested in his answer like this instead:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Title = "Sold";
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Genre = "Sold";
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Price = Decimal.Zero;
}
```

Note we changed the last line to set the price to `Decimal.Zero`. This is so we can show sold games properly.

This code is untested, but it should clue you into how to fix the errors you're experiencing.

For error 3, you can maybe do a `tryParse` statement like so:

```
decimal temp;
aNewGame[newGameEntryIndex].Price = 
    Decimal.tryParse(tbPrice.Text, out temp)? temp : Decimal.Parse("0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in the delete button click is doing too much, which likely is causing your first two errors.

If they click to delete the first item, assuming SelectedIndex is 0, then you should be able to call:

```
aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Title = "Sold";
```

Note: if SelectedIndex is 1, then you click the first item, then you'll need to subtract one.

This would make your click event look like this:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Title = "Sold";
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Genre = "Sold";
    aNewGame[cmbDelete.SelectedIndex].Price.ToString("Sold");   // There's another bug here
}
```

Comment: For the line with "There's another bug here", try to figure out what effects that line has.  What does it do?

Comment: the line is suppose to convert a decimal to a string to list it as sold

Comment: It does convert the decimal to a string... but then what happens with the result?